# Why object looks pink color in texture paint when i reopen file?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I had complete the paint on the object in Texture paint mode, after some time I had reopen that file, an object converted to pink color,why its happening like that.give me suggestion...

Comment: can you upload your file? It seems that your file lost the path of the texture (If the texture is an image).

Comment: pink in texture view is a missing texture